# AWS SNS sending emails to a topic with subscriptions pending confirmation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I had a Lambda function send a test message to an SNS topic to be emailed to two email addresses. It somehow created an infinite loop, and I'm getting 10-20 emails per minute. I tried to delete the topic's subscriptions to those two emails, but it wouldn't allow it because the subscriptions are "Pending confirmation." (Confirmations have never been sent to confirm the emails.) Then I tried to stop the emails by deleting the Lambda function and the topic, but the emails continue.

Any suggestions on how to stop AWS from sending these emails?

Here is my Lambda code that generated the problem. The function has been removed, but I'm still getting emails:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sourceRegion = 'xxxx';
const destRegion = 'yyyy';

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const sourceSNS = new AWS.SNS({region: sourceRegion});
    const destSNS = new AWS.SNS({region: destRegion});
    
    const topicArn = event.topic_arn;
    const message = JSON.stringify({
        Message: event.NewStateReason
    });
    
    const sourceParams = {
        Message: message,
        TopicArn: "xxxxxxx"
    };
    const destParams = {
        Message: message,
        TopicArn: "yyyyyyy"
    };
    
    const sourceResult = await sourceSNS.publish(sourceParams).promise();
    const destResult = await destSNS.publish(destParams).promise();
    
    console.log('Message ID: ' + sourceResult.MessageId);
    console.log('Message: ' + sourceResult.MessageId);
    
    return {
        status: 'success',
        message_id: sourceResult.MessageId
    };
```

Comment: You can try changing lambda execution role by denying it access to sns.

Comment: How can I do that since the lambda function has been deleted?

Comment: So what is generating this "loop"? Is it SNS->lambda->sns->lambda?

Comment: I edited my question to show my code. It may have something to do with the use of JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was created by "**an SNS triggering the Lambda function and the Lambda function publishing to the same SNS topic. For example, SNSTopicOne => LambdaFunction => SNSTopicOne.**"

Apparently, according to AWS support, the email messages were put into queue before I deleted the Lambda function and it just took a long time for the queue to be cleared. Support may have cleared the queue manually at some point. Nice to have this resolved since I received a few thousand emails!